# Problem with python in print function using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, printing

What is output of code:

```py
print({True:'yes', 1:'no', 1.0:'maybe'})
```

Please explain it with answer

Answer (score 0):

In Python dictionary, you cannot have duplicate keys. What is happening in your case is that all the keys in your dictionary evaluate to the boolean value `True`.

`True, 1.0 and 1 all are equal to -> True`

So what is happening is that first the value with key `True` gets a value 'yes' then its value is overridden by `'no'` and finally by `'maybe'`

Hence you have a resulting dictionary with only one key `True` with value `'maybe'`

So basically this is happening:

True:'yes'    == True:'yes' 
1:'no'        == True:'no' 
1.0:'maybe'   == True:'maybe' 
(because 1, 1.0 and True all evaluated to boolian `True`)

Comment: *"What is happening in your case is that all the keys in your dictionary evaluate to the boolean value True."* - No, they all hash to 1